# no default repositories in yum

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I am trying to install gtk-murrine-engine on my RedHat Linux Client 5.5 using yum install. It says package not available. It appears that there only exists some local repositories in yum , pertaining to my company use. Is there any way i can add the default repositories that normally exists , so that i can install other applications too??

PS: It is not a single case. I have been trying to install other packages too and gives the same error.

Comment: Do you have a valid RHN license?

Comment: Please post the output of `yum repolist`. Is your http-proxy set up properly?

Comment: If the **Powers That Be** decided it was **Holiest Company Policy** to offer only some repositories with specific software in them, you'd have to take it up with them. That said, non-official RHEL packages (but 1/2 official, maintained by the Fedora proyect) are offered by [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux doesn't use standard HTTP yum repositories, but rather uses a RHN plugin for yum, so there are no "default repositories" apart from having the yum-rhn-plugin installed (and registering the host on RHN, of course).

**HOWEVER**, the `gtk-murrine-engine` package is actually part of [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), so just set up EPEL repositories as described in the link, and then you'll be able to install the package with a 'yum install gtk-murrine-engine'.  Make sure you've got the RHN plugin set up properly, because you might need dependencies from RHN.

Comment: ive kept on searching for default repositories of red hat in google . NOw i know why i didnt get any good answers. Thanks